# Java - Import external code (in intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I want to import the libary Speex that I have as java source code. I copied the speex directory with all classes to src/speex/... and imported it with

```
import speex.SpeexEncoder;
```

But Intellij says "Cannot resolve symbol SpeexEncoder. Why? How Can I import that "libary"?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [Module Import](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/import-existing-sources-module-structure.html).

Comment: I imported it as a module. Nothing changed :/

Comment: Actually, I think I was wrong on that last comment. You want to import this as a library and then add the dependency on it to your module. Try following the steps at [Creating a module library and adding it to module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d1137129e176)

Comment: The Intellij Helpsite is more confusing than helpful. Can you maybe desribe what you mean?

Comment: I think the steps listed under the section I linked are more descriptive than I could be. It tells you step-by-step how to add a dependency to an existing module.

Comment: Do I have to copy the module files to a specific place? I tried the instructions in your links 1 on 1 and only says "Empty Libary" after I followed each step.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you know what code I want to import. You find it under JSpeex/src/java/org in this "module" http://splashurl.com/kgk72n2

Comment: Ok I solved it by "simply" create the directory structure in intellij manually org/xiph/speex.* what a crappy solution but it works

Comment: Sounds like you could also have created a library to solve this...